# Calculation error in bilinear transformation with alglib in C#

Tags: c#, alglib

For a project I am trying a transformation from the z-transforms to s-transforms. For this I wrote the code that uses the bilinear transformation and checked the results with Matlab. Unfortunately they are wrong and I don't see the error. Maybe someone can help me on the hint.

```
public double[]  BiliTransf(double[] a, double Ts)
{
    int n = a.Length;
    double[] bil_p = { 2, Ts };
    double[] bil_m = { 2, -Ts };

    init[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
         init[i] = 0;
    }
    int j;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        // (1+s)^i
        s_p = init;
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            alglib.convr1d(s_p, 1+j, bil_p, 2, out s2_p);
            s_p = s2_p;
        }
        // (1-s)^n-1-i
        s_m = init;
        for (j = 0; j < n-1-i; j++)
        {
            alglib.convr1d(s_m, 1+j, bil_m, 2, out s2_m);
            s_m = s2_m;
        }

        // s_m * s_p
        alglib.convr1d(s_m, s_m.Length, s_p, s_p.Length, out s2_m);
        VektorMulti(ref s2_m,  a[n-1-j]);
        VektorAddV2ToV1(ref a_cont, ref s2_m);
    }
    return a_cont;
}
```

Call C# Fbk:

```
a_tf = sv.BiliTransf(new double { 1, 0.5, 0.1}, 0.05);
a_tf[0]/a_tf[0] ; a_tf[0]/a_tf[1] ; a_tf[0]/a_tf[2]);
```

Result: a0: 1 / a1: -35,56 / a2: 4266,67

Call Matlab:

```
H = tf([1 0.5 0.1],[1 0.5 0.1 ],0.05)
sysc = d2c(H, 'tustin')
```

Result: a0: 1 / a1: 120/ a2: 4267

Comment: Is matlab using a single or double precision?  It looks lime in matlab the a2 value is loosing precision by dropping the fractional portion of the number.  So the number is being converted to an integer.

Comment: I think Matlab uses only half-precision, but that doesn't explain the large deviation of a1, does it ?

Comment: A double is a 64 bit floating point while a single is 32 bits.  If a conversion to an integer was being performed than that would explain the loss of precision.  Matlab default to a double.   Are you using DllImport to call the method?  Check the DLLImport definition for the DLL.  Also make sure you are using same version of matlab runtime library as the version of Matlab that was used to build the dll.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I expressed myself a little misleadingly. The Matlab function returns the correct result. For a C# project where I don't have Matlab, I implemented the above function using alglib and tested it with Matlab.

Comment: Why not just create a dll from matlab.  You can install in other machines by downloading the matlab runtime library and call through DLLImport.

Comment: This was also my first idea, unfortunately this is also not possible for licensing reasons

Comment: The matlab runtime library does not require licensing.  You only need licensing on the one machine that you create the dll and need the tool kit so you can create the dll.

Comment: Hm okay, thank you. But actually I would rather do it with my function and provide the error.